# Alot of Trash Upload file using dropzone If User don't press submit button

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I have a form that using dropzone to upload images
The problem is when users have been uploaded images but not submit the form and leave my site
it caused trash images if many users perform the same behavior.
what is the best way to upload images using dropzone.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share a code sample of what you have done so far

Comment: ```$(dropzoneElement).dropzone({
    maxFiles: 1,
    url: yourUrl
});```
Dropzone requires a url to working. If users input images, it's uploaded to the server, after that user leaves out my site although the form is unsubmitted, I caused the images uploaded become trash.

Comment: Please edit the question summary and add your code sample.